# Set table headings to bold with latex (eisvogel template)

Tags: tables, longtable, pandoc

I'm having trouble figuring out how to set the table headings to bold when using the eisvogel.tex template file. I suspect it's a longtable setting, but I've been unable to find out which parameter to tweak. I've found documentation for Longtable, but I've not found a relevant setting. Most online posts relate to setting table heading to bold inline with the text, but I'd need to be able to do this as a global setting/style if this is possible.

Below is the snippet of eisvogel I've been trying to edit. I hope I can somehow set the table heading to bold, and perhaps a different colour here.

```
%
% tables

$if(tables)$
\definecolor{table-head-color}{HTML}{0066A1} % Colour for header row
\definecolor{table-row-color}{HTML}{0066A1}
\definecolor{table-rule-color}{HTML}{0066A1}

%\arrayrulecolor{black!40}
\arrayrulecolor{table-rule-color}     % color of \toprule, \midrule, \bottomrule
\setlength\arrayrulewidth{0.1ex} % thickness of midrule?
\setlength\heavyrulewidth{0.0ex}      % thickness of \toprule, \bottomrule
\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.5}     % spacing (padding)


$if(table-use-row-colors)$
\let\oldlongtable\longtable
\let\endoldlongtable\endlongtable
\renewenvironment{longtable}{
\rowcolors{3}{table-row-color!100}{}  % row color
% \rowcolor{table-head-color!100} % This produces an error
\oldlongtable} {
\endoldlongtable
\global\rownum=0\relax}
$endif$

$endif$
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! Where does eisvogel template comes from? Do you have a link to it? Please add it to your question.

Comment: @Mensch - https://github.com/Wandmalfarbe/pandoc-latex-template

Comment: thanks @DG' - that's the one. I have made a few modifications, but nothing specific to tables except changing the colour of the row lines